# How to specify a range of values in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel report that has two columns `'Site Name'` and `'Asset IP Address'` in it. I have uploaded a sample report [here](http://1drv.ms/1p33Gek). I need a report that shows me the range IP by site, like this:

1. Assessment Site 1 192.0.2.134 – 192.0.2.201
2. Assessment Site 2 192.0.2.203 – 192.0.2.250 and so on

I have tried using `VLOOKUP` and `CountIF` but I am unable to make this work. Any suggestions are most appreciated. Thanks in  advance.

Comment: Show us your code, maybe we can fix it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a purely formula-based solution then, assuming you put e.g. *Assessment Site 1* in E2, this **array formula**** in F2:

=INDEX($B$2:$B$33,MATCH(MIN(IF($A$2:$A$33=E2,0+SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$33,".",""))),IF($A$2:$A$33=E2,0+SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$33,".","")),0))&" - "&INDEX($B$2:$B$33,MATCH(MAX(IF($A$2:$A$33=E2,0+SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$33,".",""))),IF($A$2:$A$33=E2,0+SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$33,".","")),0))

Copying down will give similar results for *Sites* listed in E3, E4, etc.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for your question. You know VBA??
Step 1: You press Alt + F11 to display VBA Editor
Step 2: Select menu Insert/Module
Step 3: Select menu Insert/Procedure
 - Name: type 'FindIP'
 - In group box Type, choose Function
Click OK
Step 4: Type this code:

```
Public Function FindIP(SiteName As String, SiteNameRange As Range, IPRange As Range) As String
Dim RangeOfIP As String
RangeOfIP = ""
For i = 1 To SiteNameRange.Rows.Count
    If (SiteNameRange.Cells(i, 1).Value = SiteName) Then
        RangeOfIP = RangeOfIP + IPRange.Cells(i, 1).Value + " - "
    End If
Next i
FindIP = RangeOfIP
End Function
```

Step 5: Close VBA Editor
Step 6: Copy column Site Name and remove duplicate (Data/Remove Duplicates)
Step 7: Right each Site Name Item, type function FindIP(SiteNameItem,SiteNameRange,IPRange)